# What is the rule of the name of the packages that start with number?

Tags: android, naming-conventions

The package naming convention in Android is:

```
com.organizationName.appName
```

But if the organizationName or the appName starts with a number or underscore, it becomes a invalid name, since android doesn't accept words that start with number or underscore.

For example:

`com.1organizationName.appName` is invalid

What is the convention to rename this package?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the official ["Naming a Package"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) java documentation, it has the following statement:

> In some cases, the internet domain name may not be a valid package
>   name. This can occur if the domain name **contains a hyphen or other
>   special character**, if the package name **begins with a digit or other
>   character that is illegal to use as the beginning of a Java name**, or
>   if the package name **contains a reserved Java keyword, such as "int".**
>   In this event, the ***suggested convention is to add an underscore***.

So in your case, it would be `com._1organizationname.appname`

EDIT: Just found this in the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package):

> A full Java-language-style package name for the application. The name
>   should be unique. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters
>   ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). **However, individual
>   package name parts may only start with letters.**

So apparently it's *not* quite Java-style. Unfortunately, it looks like your best bet in this case would in fact be to spell out the number, e.g. `com.oneorganizationname.appname`.

Comment: The problem is that Android also doesn't accept com._1organizationname.appname

Comment: Updated my answer. Android apparently doesn't completely match the Java specs for package naming.

Answer (score 2):

The naming convention is merely to help you create a unique package name for the Play market.  If you use your company's website address backwards (i.e. com.websitename.appname), then it's unlikely another app in the Play market will have it.  You can name the package whatever you want so you can spell the number out to make it easier (com.oneOrganizationName.appName).

Answer (score 1):

See [**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package) about the "package" attribute in the manifest:

> A full Java-language-style package name for the application. The name
>   should be unique. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase letters
>   ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However, individual
>   package name parts may only start with letters. To avoid conflicts
>   with other developers, you should use Internet domain ownership as the
>   basis for your package names (in reverse). For example, applications
>   published by Google start with com.google. You should also never use
>   the com.example namespace when publishing your applications.
>
> The package name serves as a unique identifier for the application.
>   It's also the default name for the application process (see the
>    element's process process attribute) and the default
>   task affinity of an activity (see the  element's
>   taskAffinity attribute).

Answer (score 0):

you can try **co.m_1organizationName.appName** or **co.m1organizationName.appName** this way your package will not be absurd and the address will be more meaningful.

Answer (score -4):

You know, it only costs like $5 to register a new domain name.  Just register oneorganizationName.com and use that.  You know it will be unique, you know it will be a valid package name, and now you know that phishers and spoofers won't be registering oneorganizationName.com for themselves to trick your customers.

Comment: What if the organization I'm registering literally has a number as the first character in its name?