# Cant create project with number in package name

Tags: cordova

I have domain with number in the url, also already app in google play, with number in package name.

when I try to create new project with cordova 3.6 I get this error: "package name must look like com.company.name" when I remove the number everythink is ok. is there some way to pass the 'package name checking' and just build with whatever I want? as clearly this test is failing with no reason.

this ok:

```
 create HelloWorld  example.net HelloWorld
```

this fail:

```
 create HelloWorld  example1.net HelloWorld
```

I know that it should be '*domain*.*name*' and not opposite but the apk is already in the play store and google accept it

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the rule of the name of the packages that start with number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041857/what-is-the-rule-of-the-name-of-the-packages-that-start-with-number)

Comment: @Simon thank but its differnt cases.. I dont have number in the start of package, my apk is already in play store and have 1000+ downloads so I cant change the name :)

Comment: create it w/o and then update the package name in `config.xml` before running the first build.