# AndroidManifest Package Name error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, package-name

> error: attribute 'package' in  tag is not a valid Android package name: 'com.familyfit.google.22pushups'.
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: attribute 'package' in  tag is not a valid Android package name: 'com.familyfit.google.22pushups'., sources=[/Users/manlokwong/Desktop/familyfit/22-pushups-android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:2], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

I don't know why I cannot set this package name.
`com.familyfit.google.22pushups`

Comment: maybe because the last word is starting with a number

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12042111/6169668) and also this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273892/android-package-name-convention?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

You can not start package name sections with numbers, spaces, underscore, etc

Comment: Just a quick note: you cannot start any parts of the package name with numbers, spaces or special characters. In this case it's "22pushups" that's an invalid package name part. You can do something like "app22pushups" instead.